DBT - 'bool' object is not callable
I'm trying to add a test to a dbt model. However there's an error while running dbt test. I tried to strip down the test to a minimal but still couldn't find where the problem is. The error says
Compilation error in test count_my_model_ (models\my_project\mart\_my_project_mart_models.yaml) 'bool' object is not callable

How to solve this error?
The project structure is:
dbt_main
-- |marcos
   |models
    --|my_project
       --|mart
          --_my_project_mart_models.yaml
          --my_model.sql
   |target
   |tests
    --|generic
      --| count.sql 
   |dbt_project.yml

In the _my_project_mart_models.yaml :
models:
   - name: my_model
     tests:
       - count
     columns:
       - name: col1
         data_type: string
       - name: id
         data_type: string  

and the count.sql looks like this:
{% test count (model) %}
select *
from {{ model }}
where id is not null
{% endtest %} 

